# Where is storing events log?

Tags: solidity, events

I can't understand where are these events log data is stored?

I can access to my logs by

```js
myContract.allEvents({
    fromBlock: 2139049,
    toBlock: 'latest'
  }, function(error, event){
      console.log("event : ",event);
});
```

But, can i access this logs after one year? Or they'll be removed?
And where is this logs are storing?

Answer (score 4):

Event logs are stored within transaction receipts, which are stored in blocks.  You will be able to access your event logs for as long as the network remains active.

Comment: Is there reason do not use event log for storing some data? I just need to store ipfs hash in each transaction, and later return those hashes in correct order. As i understand, reason is that contract can't access event log itself?

Comment: It is fairly common practice for a dApp to read data from contract event logs (rather than from the contract), as it is often a cheaper form of storage. You are correct in that the contract cannot access the event log directly. As for returning the hashes/events in the correct order, I do not believe web3 does this by default.

Comment: I will order it by frontend js scripts. I'm very surprised, since I read that the logs are stored on the nodes and they can retire. If it's not, so this is very cool, because of cheap

Comment: Event logs will always be recoverable since transaction receipts are stored within blocks.